# Why Accord.MachineLearning has been duplicated in the Solution Explorer References list?

Tags: f#, accord.net, paket

I am starting a new `Console Application` `F#` project in `Visual Studio version 15.8.1`. Using `paket`, I installed these packages:

```
Accord
Accord.Math
Accord.Statistics
Accord.MachineLearning
```

So far so good. But when I installed `Accord.MachineLearning.gpl` in addition to the above packages I got a duplicate entry for `Accord.MachineLearning` in the `Solution Explorer` `References` list:

```
Accord
Accord.Math
Accord.Statistics
Accord.MachineLearning
Accord.MachineLearning // duplicate here
Accord.MachineLearning.gpl
```

Questions:

1) Is this a problem?

2) How to avoid this?

3) Is there a way to eliminate the duplicate?

Comment: I imagine you have typed the above list to explain what you see in the Solution Explorer's References list. I suggest you tell us what entries you find in the project file. That might enlighten us.

Comment: I wasn't able to  reproduce the reported behavior in presumably the same environment after installing the first 4 packages with `paket install`, and then adding `Accord.MachineLearning.GPL` with `paket add --interactive`. References do look fine.

Comment: @BentTranberg - Since I cannot reproduce the problem anymore I cannot show what is in the project file.

Comment: @GeneBelitski - I can no longer reproduce the problem. Followed the same steps and now I do not get a duplicate Àccord.MachineLearning` entry. Thanks for looking into this.